# Tudo é objeto em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, funções, objetos

Estou muito confuso em relação ao que é objeto e o que pode se comportar como objeto, veja o exemplo que criei para ilustrar a situação:

```
def subtrai(x,y):
    return (x - y)

class OpeMatematica(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def soma(self):
        return (self.x + self.y)

soma = OpeMatematica(10,10)
print(soma.soma())

print(subtrai(100, 10))

s = subtrai
print(s(50,10))

s = soma
s.x = 10
s.y = 100
print(s.soma())
```

Criei uma função `subtrai` que executa uma subtração e criei uma classe `OpeMatematica` com os atributos `x` e `y` e um método `soma`.

Nesta linha:

```
soma = OpeMatematica(10,10)
print(soma.soma())
```

Instanciei minha classe `OpeMatematica` e invoquei o método `soma` e obtive o resultado `20`.

Nesta linha:

```
print(subtrai(100, 10))
```

Invoquei a função `subtrai` e obtive o resultado `90`.

Nesta linha descobri algo interessante:

```
s = subtrai
print(s(50,10))
```

Veja que eu atribui a variável `s` a função `subtrai` e a mesma passou assumir o comportamento da função `subtrai` veja `s(50,10)`, é como se a função `subtrai` fosse um objeto e pudesse ser instanciada, o resultado da operação é `40`.

E nesta linha tem outra curiosidade:

```
s = soma
s.x = 10
s.y = 100
print(s.soma())
```

Atribui a `s` o objeto `soma` e `s` passou a ser um objeto do tipo `OpeMatematica`, acessando os atributos `x` e `y` e invocando o método `soma`, o resultado obtido é `110`.

Agora estou confuso a respeito do que é um objeto em Python, analisando este código eu concluí que tudo parece ser um objeto em Python até mesmo **variáveis** e **funções**, alguém poderia me explicar porque Python tem este comportamento, e o que é um objeto ou uma classe em Python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Esse é um conceito bem diferente. Isso quer dizer que as [funções de Python são de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101). Ou seja, entre outras características a função pode ser atribuída para uma variável (obviamente também pode ser passada como argumento ou retorno de função). A própria função (código) é tratada como se fosse um valor, um dado. Em geral isso é feito com [funções anônimas ou *lambdas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), mas é possível fazer o mesmo diretamente em uma função existente, como foi feito no exemplo.

Nesse caso a variável irá guardar a função e não um resultado dela. O tipo dessa variável é `FunctionType`. É claro que concretamente ela não guarda o código fonte da função (até poderia, mas não conheço nenhuma linguagem que faz isso, seria ineficiente e arriscado), existem mecanismos que se referenciam à função e o compilador/interpretador sabe como tratar essa variável de forma diferente, e seu acesso se dá como uma chamada de função, já que ela **é** uma função.

Esse conceito nada tem a ver com orientação a objeto. Mas pode ser que a forma interna de armazenar a função na variável seja através de um objeto ([ainda sem mesmo usar OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101)). O mais tradicional, principalmente quando não é uma [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), é que seja apenas um [ponteiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)). No caso do Python realmente há um objeto controlando isso, mas é um objeto como outro qualquer. Um dos seus membros é o [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html) que permite fazer a chamada.

Em Python nem tudo é um objeto no sentido que as pessoas esperam, a própria sintaxe da classe já dá um dica que precisa ser explícito quanto a isso. Deixando de lado OOP, o conceito do tipo `object`, de uma certa forma, podemos dizer que tudo em qualquer linguagem é um objeto. Se não é um objeto, é o que então? Claro que essa terminologia pode ser estranha para alguns, mas ela é real. Em C você tem objetos, só não são do mesmo jeito que em Java, por exemplo.

Uma função possui uma infraestrutura em um objeto que permite que ela seja armazenada nele e depois ser chamada. Isto é um mecanismo interno que garante a chamada. Como tudo em computação não existe mágica, existe engenharia. Alguém viu um problema, e achou uma solução viável para resolver o problema.

Uma das formas de chamar uma função armazenada em um objeto é através do compilador chamando a função usando a variável de forma direta. Com a ajuda do compilador a chamada fica mais conveniente e elegante, conforme foi mostrado na pergunta.

Se não tiver certeza se pode chamá-la, pode verificar antes:

```
s = 0
if hasattr(s, '__call__')
    s(50, 10)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Reflection/HasAttr.py).

Isso não chamará nada e não dará erro, porque neste exemplo a variável `s` não é "chamável", é um inteiro e não uma função. A verificação se a variável poderia ser chamada como função foi feita antes de chamar, evitando o erro. Esta forma permite resolver um monte de problemas de forma conveniente sem recorrer à orientação a objeto.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a finalidade do `callable(s)` e o `hasattr(s, '__call__')` poderia me explicar?

Comment: Veja se melhorou.

Comment: Consegui entender agora.

Comment: A função `callable` serve para testar se um objeto pode ser invocado ou não, ela retorna `True` ou `False`. Portanto não se pode usá-la para invocar métodos/funções nem no [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) ou no [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable).

Comment: @fernandosavio tirei essa parte, tava confundindo mais que ajudando mesmo.

Comment: Acho que daria até para trocar `if hasattr(s, '__call__')`  por `if callable(s)`... Dessa maneira fica mais correto, apesar da [discussão](https://bugs.python.org/issue7006) ser um pouco longa, `callable` faz uma checagem no PyObject em C para ver se pode ser invocado (acredito que [este campo](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_call)) e `has_attr` pode ter problemas em casos específicos.