# Listas dentro de listas: mesmo fatiando, há conexão entre as listas

Tags: python, lista, slice

Estou estudando listas e acontece um comportamento que não entendi.

Sei que quando igualo uma lista a outra, uma conexão entre elas é criada. E que quando uso fatiamento de uma lista, crio uma cópia da lista (sem conexão entre elas, ou seja, quando muda em muda, não muda em outra). Entretanto, quando há listas dentro de listas, mesmo com fatiamento, é feito conexão entre as listas.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> a = [[2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> print(b)
[[2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
>>> b[0][1] = 100
>>> print(a[0][1])
100
>>> print(b)
[[2, 100, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
>>> print(a)
[[2, 100, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Ou seja, mudou na lista `b`, também mudou na lista `a`.
Por que isso aconteceu?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma explicação mais detalhada.

Cada lista é um objeto separado. não existe "lista a" ou "lista b". Em python, diferente de muitas outras linguagens, as variáveis são apenas **nomes** que se *referem* a **objetos**.

Vamos analisar o código linha a linha:

```
a = [[2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Essa linha está criando 3 listas. Uma das lista possui referências a outras duas listas dentro dela. o nome `a` está apontando para uma das 3 listas criadas, aquela que contém as outras duas. Dizer que essa é a "lista a" é uma forma mais simples de dizer, porém, na verdade essa não é a lista `a`. `a` é somente um "nome" que "faz referência" à lista.

```
b = a[:]
```

Essa linha faz duas coisas: ao usar `[:]` com uma lista, é criada uma nova lista, onde são copiadas todas as referências que estavam dentro da lista original. Em seguida é criado um nome `b` para se referir a essa cópia.

Neste ponto, você tem 4 listas: São elas, na ordem que foram criadas:

```
PRIMEIRA LISTA:  [2, 3, 5]
SEGUNDA LISTA: [1, 3, 5]
TERCEIRA LISTA: [(PRIMEIRA LISTA), (SEGUNDA LISTA)]
QUARTA LISTA: [(PRIMEIRA LISTA), (SEGUNDA LISTA)]
```

Veja que o conteúdo da terceira lista é o mesmo da quarta lista,  ou seja, **foram copiadas as referências** que apontam para duas primeiras listas... pois é isso que o slice `[:]` faz, **copiar referências**.

Sendo assim, não importa se você use `a` ou `b` para se referenciar à terceira ou à quarta lista, pois, no fim do processamento, ao mexer nas listas internas, estará mexendo na mesma lista!

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Sim, sei que tudo em Python é objeto, e se tudo é objeto, porque não acontece o mesmo comportamento com variáveis numéricas (ao igualar a = 2 e b = a, quando mudar em b , muda em a , e vice-versa) ?

Comment: @ViniciusViana porque você não está "mudando em `b`"... `b` é só um nome, a única coisa que ele consegue fazer é referir a objetos. O que você tem que "mudar" é o objeto. No exemplo o objeto seria o `2` - objetos do tipo `int` não são mutáveis, logo não é possível mutá-los. Ao fazer `b = b + 1`, você estará criando um novo objeto do tipo `int`, o `3`, (pois `b+1` cria um novo objeto) e fazendo `b` apontar para este novo objeto criado. O `a` continua apontando para o objeto `2`.

Comment: @ViniciusViana já no caso de listas, por exemplo `lista[0] = 10` está efetivamente mudando a lista, particularmente o primeiro objeto que ela se refere (listas são coleções de referências). `lista.append(12)` também muda a lista. Uma nova lista não é criada.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender com essa explicação

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando *slice* que nada mais é que uma referência para a lista concreta, assim como qualquer lista, então se mudar algo pela referência estará mudando na lista original, é a mesma coisa internamente. As variáveis são diferentes, mas o objeto que elas se referem é o mesmo.

Se não deseja isto precisa fazer uma cópia profunda onde cada elemento é copiado de verdade para uma nova lista concreta isolada. Assim:

```
import copy

a = [[2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[0][1] = 100
print(a)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5C8tmH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lwhzhjvr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ListReference.py).

Tem outras formas de obter o mesmo, mas o que precisa entender é o conceito de referência e de cópia real. Claro que a referência é super rápida e tem complexidade de tempo constante (O(1)) e a cópia real é bem mais lenta e tem complexidade linear (O(n)).

Um detalhe importante baseando-se em outros pontos desta página: Python não é diferente de outras linguagens, todas funcionam igual. Há autores sobre Python que vendem esta ideia que ela é diferente, mas não é. Em geral quem aprende só por essas fontes acreditam nisto. Há diferenças do Python em relação a outras linguagens, mas estes conceitos são universais. Em todas linguagens tudo que é estado é objeto, tem [resposta aqui no site sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), e [variáveis são sempre nomes para endereços de memória onde tem os objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Pode interessar também: [Tudo é objeto em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109102/101).

Comment: Correção: Slices em Python não são referências para a lista concreta - são novas listas mesmo. O problema do AP é que as listas internas, essas sim, são as mesmas tanto na lista original quanto na copiada por slice. O deepcopy resolve, claro.

Comment: Talvez seja só questão de nomenclatura, entendo o que está dizendo, vou pensar uma outra forma de escrever o mesmo de forma mais clara, *slice* é uma referência, e claro, a lista tb, por isso ficou um pouco confuso o que eu tentei dizer.

Comment: Não - não é nomenclatura. Slice é outra lista - e de fato é uma forma de se fazer uma cópia raza de outra lista. Tanto que tenho um projeto (que falta uma polida de testes, setup.py) que tem uma classe de "listview" que implementa as slices como referências.

Comment: https://github.com/jsbueno/extralist/blob/master/extralist/slicedview.py

Comment: Em python, as variáveis são nomes, mas armazenam somente referências. Não é possível armazenar nada em um nome a não ser uma referência. Essa é a diferença das outras linguagens. Além disso todas as passagens de parâmetro são por valor, onde o valor é uma referência.

Comment: @nosklo Variáveis são nomes, coloquei um *link* que mostra isto. Como são nomes em nenhuma linguagem se armazena alguma coisa em nomes. Armazena-se algo na memória onde os nomes são alias para esses endereços. Isto é um conceito universal, nenhuma linguagem é diferente disto. Algumas linguagem permitem colocar o objeto direto nessa posição ou por uma referência para o objeto. Outras linguagens, e não só Python, várias outras permitem ter apenas referências. Conceitualmente não muda nada.

Comment: @nosklo Em essência todas as linguagens (tem uma ou outra exceção, mas nada importante) as linguagens passam argumentos (e não parâmetros, são coisas distintas) sempre por valor, sendo que em alguns casos o valor é a referência (em Python e outras linguagem sempre é). Python não tem nada de diferente, mas alguém escreveu que tem e quem não conhece os conceitos com mais profundidade acha que é verdade, mas não é. Claro que Python tem diferenças em relação a algumas linguagens, mas ela não tem nada de especial, nada exclusivo.

Comment: Em algumas linguagens é possível passar a referência, ou seja, ao alterar a referência dentro da função, o nome passa a se referir a outra coisa fora da função. Em python isso não é possível, pois só existe passagem por valor (cópia), mesmo que o valor seja uma referência, ela é copiada, ou seja, não é possível alterar a referência original através da função

Comment: @nosklo agora você está falando de outra coisa. E na verdade dá, só que precisa usar um truque :) A única forma de proibir é não ter referência alguma na linguagem, ela é toda baseada em referências.

Answer (score 0):

> mudou na lista b, também mudou na lista a

Você **não** mudou a lista `b`. O que você mudou foi uma lista que está *dentro* de `b`. Essa lista interna é compartilhada entre `a` e `b`, porque a operação de *slice* (fatiamento) faz uma [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Veja:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = a[:]

a[0] = [7, 8, 9]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Perceba que, apesar de `a` ter mudado, `b` continuou idêntica. No entanto, se fizer isso aqui:

```
a[1][0] = 0

print(a)
print(b)
```

A alteração será vista tanto em `a` quanto em `b`, porque neste segundo caso a alteração aconteceu *na lista interna*, e essa lista interna é a mesma em `a` e `b`.

Se você quiser copiar as listas internas também, utilize `copy.deepcopy` conforme [indicado nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341043/98734).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Pelo que entendi na documentação do python, o slice cria uma shallow copy, que é um novo objeto composto A a partir do primeiro objeto B e copia as refêrências (locais da memória dos objetos) dos objetos contidos em A para dentro para dentro de B. Já o deep copy (A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.) cria um novo objeto composto B a partir de A e a partir de cada objeto em A , cria um novo objeto a partir de cada objeto em A, até o nível mais profundo.

Comment: @ViniciusViana Exatamente. Uma operação de shallow copy só copia o objeto mais externo, já uma deep copy copia tudo. Esse conceito não é específico do Python, quase toda linguagem possui essa distinção. Operações de shallow copy são mais comuns porque são muito mais rápidas e ocupam muito menos memória (já que os objetos internos ficam compartilhados).